# How do I render a view in front of the iOS status bar in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm currently making a React Native app using Material Design components. When creating my drawer, I realized that it does not cover up the status bar at the top of the app. However, when I looked at the Google Keep, Google AdSense, and Google Analytics apps, their drawers all render in front of the status bar.

Here's a picture of my app. The status bar at the top of the app is completely visible.

[image: my app]

But here's a screenshot of the Google Keep app where the drawer renders in front of the status bar.

[image: google keep]

How can I achieve this effect using React Native?

Answer (score -1):

Add this code to your appDelegate.m inside `didfinishlaunching`:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

Cheers :)